# Quand utiliser « quelque … que » ou « quoique » ?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions

Page 62 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker:

> quelque ... que = *whatever, however*. Quelque and the interrogative adjective quel combine with the relative pronoun que to mean whatever. The verb that follows is always in the subjunctive. Before a noun quelque is an adjective and is variable.
>
> **Quelques** peurs **que** vous ayez, conquérez-les.
>   *Whatever fears you have, conquer them.*

D'après Larousse, [quoique](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/quoique/65798?q=quoique#65049) est une conjonction et :

> 1. Indique la concession ; bien que, encore que :
>      *Quoique nous soyons à la fin juillet, il y a encore beaucoup de monde à Paris.*
> 2. Indique une réserve portant sur un qualificatif :
>      *Quoique riche, il n'était guère généreux.*
> 3. Introduit une objection après un temps de réflexion :
>      *J'irais bien jusqu'à la place, quoique ça me fera une trop longue marche.*

Je vois que le sens 1 de *quoique* n'existe pas dans *quelque … que*. Ainsi, avec le sens 1, ces deux mots ne sont pas interchangeables.

Si on considère les sens 2 et 3, quelles sont les différences d'usage entre *quelque … que* et *quoique* ?

Answer (score 1):

Je ne comprends pas vraiment la question, « *quelque* » et « *quoique* » n'ayant pas grand chose en commun et n'étant pas interchangeables :

- « quelque » est [un adverbe qui indique une approximation](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/quelque/65617)

  Utilisé en tant que corrélatif avec « que » (quelque… que), il marque une concession avec indétermination, ce qui est très peu usité dans le langage parlé ou le langage écrit non-littéraire…

  D'ailleurs, j'ai beau essayer de trouver un exemple avec cette formulation, ça sonne forcément faux à mon oreille :

  > *Quelque de qualité que soit mon français, je ne suis pas sûr de savoir utiliser cette locution.*

  et je préfère utiliser une formulation comme :

  > *Quelle que soit la qualité de mon français, je ne suis pas sûr de savoir utiliser cette locution.*
- « quoique » est est [une conjonction](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/quoique/65798), qui me semble plus couramment utilisée, même si c'est plus rarement dans le langage parlé que dans les écrits non-littéraires…

  On utilisera bien plus facilement la forme « [bien que](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/bien_que/9173) » ou « [encore que](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/encore/29244/expression) ».

  À titre d'exemple, on dira bien plus naturellement :

  > *Quoique peu souvent utilisée, l'utilisation de « quoique » est plus naturelle.*

  qu'on peut remplacer par :

  > *Bien que peu souvent utilisée, l'utilisation de « quoique » est plus naturelle.*

Comment: *De quelque qualité que soit mon français…* c'est grammaticalement correct même si la phrase n'a pas vraiment de sens.

Answer (score 0):

Pour être franc votre question n'est pas très claire mais essayons tout de même d'y répondre.

Les deux mots, bien que proches phonétiquement, sont différents et s'emploient donc dans des expressions différentes.

Même si ce n'est pas parfaitement correct, vous pouvez remplacer « *quoique* » par « *au final* » si cela peut vous aider à comprendre le sens.

Pour « *quelque… que* » vous pouvez essayer de le remplacer par « *malgré le fait que* » mais il faudra alors modifier l'organisation de la phrase pour garder tout son sens.

Exemple :

- *Quelque couleurs que vous preniez, elles seront toujours claires* »
- *Malgré le fait que vous preniez des couleurs, elles seront toujours claires* ».

Comment: à mon oreille, l'exemple 1 « *Quelque couleurs que vous preniez* » sonne faux, ce n'est pas une tournure que j'utiliserais… Je dirais plutôt « Quelque *soit* les couleurs que vous preniez,… »

Comment: et d'ailleurs, en relisant les deux exemples, le sens de la phrase est différent, ce qui sert de contre exemple à la thèse du « quelque… que » remplaçable par « malgré le fait que »

Comment: @zmo "Quelles que soient les couleurs que vous preniez,...", pas "Quelque soit les ...".

Comment: @jlliagre au temps pour moi, je me suis *quelque* peu emmellé les pinceaux dans cette discussion sur [« *quelque que* » avec le « *quel que* »](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic5640-quelque-soit-ou-quel-que-soit.html)…

Comment: @zmo, "emmêlé", pas "emméllé" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Si je comprends bien l'origine de votre question, il y a une confusion entre "quoique" et "quoi que". "Quoique" est une conjonction qui peut se remplacer par "bien que", "malgré que"...  dans une phrase et n'a rien à voir avec "Quelque ... que".

C'est "Quoi que" qui peut s'utiliser dans le sens de "whatever". Par exemple :

```
Quoi que tu fasses, je te retrouverai.
```

En ce qui concerne l'utilisation de "quoi que" et "quelque ... que", la différence se trouve dans la mise en évidence du complément d'objet avec "quelque .. que" alors que "Quoi que" remplace le complément (dans les exemples ci-dessous, "quelque(s)" est un déterminant indéfini mais "quoi" est un pronom indéfini). Pour être complet, ont peut également utiliser la construction "Quelle que" pour insister sur le complément du verbe. Cette dernière forme est d'ailleurs plus courante que "quelque ... que".

```
Quelque peinture que tu utilises, cela s'effritera rapidement.

Quoi que tu utilises (comme peinture), cela s'effritera rapidement.

Quelle que soit la peinture que tu utilises, cela s'effritera rapidement.
```

pour reprendre votre exemple :

```
Quelques peurs que vous ayez, conquérez-le!

Quelles que soient vos peurs, conquérez-les!

Quoi que vous ayez comme peurs, conquérez-les!
```